# Inconsistent, Slow Encryption Performance with Jasypt on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, scala, jasypt

I am using Jasypt's BasicBinaryEncryptor to encrypt small amounts of binary data (around 1 KB).  I am using Scala, but I doubt that matters.

```
val encryptor = new BasicBinaryEncryptor
encryptor.setPassword(password)
val encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(bytes.toByteArray())
```

This encrypt operation can range anywhere from a few seconds, but often runs to over a minute or more.  It also seems like the first few operations run just fine, but after that it slows down.

I have tried Jasypt version 1.9.2 and 1.9.1. This operation is slow on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 (Hotspot JVM 1.8.0_45) and 15.04, but runs just fine on Mac OS X (Hotspot JVM 1.8.0_40-b25).

Any thoughts on what I can change to improve performance on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure about `BasicBinaryEncryptor` but in general the [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) class can run out of randomness and will pause until it gets more.  So if SecureRandom is being used under the hood it might account for the inconsistent performance.

Comment: Is there something I can do to help it not run out of randomness?

Comment: I think you are right.  From some quick reading, the kernel store 4,096 bits of entropy.  Running 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail' shows that on my test systems I have roughly 200 which is really low.  Not sure what to do about it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your are experiencing is caused by the salt generator used by Jasypt.`BasicBinaryEncryptor` uses a [StandardPBEByteEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.html) with the default configuration for a [SaltGenerator](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/salt/SaltGenerator.html). This results in the use of [RandomSaltGenerator](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/salt/RandomSaltGenerator.html) which uses [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (as of Jasypt v1.9.1). SecureRandom will block if not enough entropy is available, as markspace pointed out.

If you are ok with using `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` you can start your program with `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom`, which will not block.

Another option would be to configure your own encryptor and use a different SaltGenerator. Jasypt provides some fixed SaltGenerators you can use, or you can roll your own random one that doesn't use SecureRandom.

Answer (score 0):

On our Ubuntu server we installed the `haveged` package via `apt-get`.

Read about that more here: http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/

The package is not installed by default, but generates entropy.  After doing this, we were able to swap back to `/dev/random` instead of using `/dev/urandom`.